# Как правильно реализовать подключение к БД tarantool через веб-интерфейс на java?

Tags: java, база-данных, maven

Необходимо подключится к БД Тарантула с веб-морды написанной на javа, есть что то на подобии инструкции на github'е ( [connector java for tarantool](https://github.com/tarantool/tarantool-java/tree/master) ), но мне непонятен сам принцип данного коннектора, и что это библиотека/драйвер, и куда её нужно положить в своём проекте, что бы осуществить коннект к БД?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java Connector for Tarantool - это Java-библиотека. Вы либо подключаете ее к проекту как обычную maven-зависимость

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.tarantool</groupId>
  <artifactId>connector</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.2</version>
</dependency>
```

либо, если у вас Gradle

```
compile group: 'org.tarantool', name: 'connector', version: '1.7.2'
```

либо, если вы по какой-то причине до сих пор не используете инструменты управления зависимостями, кидаете к остальным jar-файлам (обычно это папка `lib`).

После чего как описан ов README настраиваете подключение, получаете экземпляр интерфейса `TarantoolClient` и пользуетесь им, для вызова команд, например:

```
client.syncOps.ping();
```

Полноценный пример использования можно посмотреть в том репозитории в тесте: https://github.com/tarantool/tarantool-java/blob/master/src/it/java/org/tarantool/TestTarantoolClient.java

Работа с tarantool, разумеется, будет вестись на серверной части вашего веб-приложения.